# use of word "Like" in the beginning of a sentence

Tags: prepositions, adjectives

> Like smaller companies, the larger companies, continue to be impacted
>   by the advancements in technology.

Can anyone help me understand what function the word "Like" has in the sentence? Is it a preposition or an adjective or something else?

Comment: Welcome to English Language Learners, and thanks for your question. Just one thought - I'm not sure where your sample sentence came from, but the comma after 'larger companies' doesn't belong there. It's not needed and confuses the meaning of the sentence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is functioning as a preposition. It forms a prepositional phrase "Like smaller companies", meaning "Similar to".

The subject of the sentence is "the larger companies", and you probably shouldn't separate the subject from the verb "continue" with a comma.

This is better than considering "like" to be an adjective.  For example it doesn't past the "movement test":  "Like smaller companies" is ok, but "smaller companies that are like" is not correct.

Comment: Thank you! But, why it can't be an adjective? (Or adjective phrase) ?

Comment: The entire phrase "like smaller companies" could be understood to **act** as an adjective phrase describing "the larger companies". But you asked about the word "like" itself. That word is not an adjective and does not function as one in this sentence either. As James K says, it is a preposition.